# Double pivoting - proxychains.conf - why should I use 2 entries?

Tags: metasploit, socks5, proxychains, pivoting

I am studying pivoting and I had a question related to double pivoting.

Reading various blogs, I read that it is a common (but not always used) practice to define two entries in the `/etc/proxychains.conf` file when performing double pivoting.

For example, in this [article](https://theyhack.me/Proxychains-Double-Pivoting/) there are 4 machines:

```
 attack <--> jumpbox1.local <--> jumpbox2.local <--> destbox.local
```

and the purpose is to reach `destbox.local` from `attack`.
So in the article, with SSH, 2 ports are opened: the 8888 on the `attack's localhost` and the 9999 on the `jumpbox1.local's localhost`.

```
attack:~$ ssh -f -N -D 127.0.0.1:8888 user@jumpbox1.local
attack:~$ ssh user@jumpbox1.local 'ssh -f -N -D 127.0.0.1:9999 user@jumpbox2.local'
```

Figuring out how encapsulation might work, I imagine something like this:

[image]

And so far it makes sense.

However, when double pivoting is done with Metasploit the process is this (as described in this [article](https://pentest.blog/explore-hidden-networks-with-double-pivoting)):

```
use auxiliary/server/socks4a 
set SRVHOST 172.16.0.20
set SRVPORT 1080
run

use auxiliary/server/socks4a 
set SRVHOST 172.16.0.20
set SRVPORT 1081
run
```

and the `proxychains.conf` file is as follows:

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/proxychains.conf
    dynamic_chain
    proxy_dns 
    tcp_read_time_out 15000
    tcp_connect_time_out 8000
    socks4  172.16.0.20 1080  # First Pivot
    socks4  172.16.0.20 1081  # Second Pivot
```

But in this case, **the socks proxies are both on the attacker's machine** (172.16.0.20) and there are not 2 proxies on 2 different machines as in the first example. So I don't understand the point of adding the second entry.
In addition it seems that even without the second entry, the last machine is reached from the attacker's machine.

Can anyone clarify this doubt for me, thank you very much!

Comment: It is prob so that no one computer sees both your source and your destination.  But this is a guess at best.

Comment: If by source and destination you mean "attack" and "destbox.local" that is clearly the case.